# Is there any way i can append things into a list in different lines?

Tags: python, list, indexing, newline

I was trying to append things into a list with each set of three elements getting appended line by line. So what I mean is:

> ```
> ex = [John, 20/9/21, 234 
>
>       Marc, 21/9/21, 53466]
> ```

So after appending each set of 3 elements line by line. I would like to find the index of the last element of each line. So in my case, I want 234 and 53466 from this list (there will be lines and lines of these sets of three elements, so I need a general way to find them).

Comment: Please put in appropriate quoting inside the list example.

Comment: You are looking for a list of lists most likely.

Answer (score 0):

If its always exactly sets of you can use array slicing

```
 ex = ['John', '20/9/21', 234, 'Marc', '21/9/21', 53466, 'Peter', '22/9/21', 93879]
 print(ex[2::3])
 >> [234, 53466, 93879]
```

`[2::3]` means start at index 2 to the end in steps of 3.

Realistically you might consider moving to 2D arrays or more advanced structures i.e. with pandas

Comment: Oh great!
This might work!
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to append a tuple of data. That way you can treat your structure as a matrix / table.

```
l = []
l.append(('John' , '21/10/21' , 238))
l.append(('Marc' , '23/06/21' , 1586))
print(l)

for row in l:
    print(row)
    for cell in row:
        print(cell)

print(l[1][1])
print(l[0][2])
```

Beware to NOT use l += ('...'), because if you then print out a certain index you will get that single character / number. So use l.append(...)!

I hope this is what you're looking for

Comment: Hello!
Thanks for the quick reply
Yeah, i think this would work, but is there any way to print the last element of the first tuple that you tried to append?